# how to install six.moves.xmlrpc_client?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm copying some code snippet from openstack, but when it runs to:

```
import six.moves.xmlrpc_client as xmlrpclib
```

I got the following error:

```
    import six.moves.xmlrpc_client as xmlrpclib
ImportError: No module named xmlrpc_client
```

I have install the `six` package. How to solve this problem?

I'm working on MacOS with python 2.7.

I tried to install but failed:

```
lichaos-MacBook-Pro:common lichao$ sudo pip install --allow-unverified xmlrpclib xmlrpclib
Collecting xmlrpclib
  xmlrpclib is potentially insecure and unverifiable.
  Downloading http://effbot.org/media/downloads/xmlrpclib-1.0.1.zip
Installing collected packages: xmlrpclib
  Running setup.py install for xmlrpclib
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/xmlrpc_handler.py from 644 to 755
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/xmlrpcserver.py from 644 to 755
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/echotest.py from 644 to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/echotest.py to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/xmlrpc_handler.py to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/xmlrpcserver.py to 755
Successfully installed xmlrpclib-1.0.1

$ sudo pip show six
---
Name: six
Version: 1.8.0
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

But when I run my program, I still got same error. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`six.moves` is a *virtual namespace*. It provides access to packages that were renamed between Python 2 and 3. As such, you shouldn't be installing anything.

By importing from `six.moves.xmlrpc_client` the developer doesn't have to handle the case where it is located at [`xmlrpclib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) in Python 2, and at [`xmlrpc.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html) in Python 3. Note that these are part of the *standard library*.

The mapping was added to [`six` version 1.5.0](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/2828c8c72e975c326722c941c921b6f93498ea22/CHANGES?at=default#cl-135); make sure you have that version or newer.

Mac comes with six version 1.4.1 pre-installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` and this will interfere with any version you install in `site-packages` (which is listed last in the sys.path).

The best work-around is to use a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and install your own version of `six` into that, together with whatever else you need for this project. Create a new virtualenv for new projects.

If you absolutely have to install this at the system level, then for this specific project you'll have to remove the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` path:

```
import sys
sys.path.remove('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python')
```

This will remove various OS X-provided packages from your path for just that run of Python; Apple installs these for their own needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried to install xmlrpclib using pip but fail, please see my update in the question. Can you please help? By the way, I'm not using Django.

Comment: @EvanLi: you do **not** need to install `xmlrpclib`. It is part of the Python standard library.

Comment: @EvanLi: What does `pip show six` show you have installed?

Comment: @EvanLi: again, you do **not** install `xmlrpclib`. That is **not the problem**. There may be a problem with the `six` meta path object here, but you don't fix it by installing `xmlrpclib`.

Comment: @EvanLi: Open up the Python interpreter and run `import six`. does that work at all? What does `six.__file__` show is imported?

Comment: six.__file__ shows '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc'

Comment: @EvanLi: that is a different version from the one in site-packages. It'll be loaded instead because it is listed earlier than `site-packages`.

Comment: @EvanLi: that is the Mac system version, and it is version 1.4.1.. hrmz, let me investigate. I see it on my system too.

Comment: @EvanLi: updated; your best option is to use a virtualenv (which isolates you from the Apple-supplied version).

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall six  
pip install six
```

should solve the issue.